# How to set status bar hidden for entire app in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to set the status bar of my entire iOS app hidden. (The app deployment target is set to iOS 7.1).

I have tried the following (and none worked):

Adding this line to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in AppDelegate.m :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

and also this line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

I have tried setting the statusBar to None for each of my View Controllers in Storyboard View --> Attributes inspector --> Simulated Metrics.

I have tried adding the key `Status bar is initially hidden` as YES in Info.plist file of my app.

None of these worked. Can anyone guide me as to what is wrong?
Btw, I am using the latest version of XCode on my Mac and latest iOS on my test device. And, all my View Controllers have been set to Landscape mode only in Attributes inspector. And the supported orientations of the app are Landscape both sides.

Comment: What kind of view controller is your root view controller?

Comment: It is a custom view controller with two labels in it, each of which segues to another VC.

Comment: info.plist file, there add View controller-based status bar appearance
 NO. And in Project setting Check on ststusbar hidden on lounch ....

Answer (score 1):

Just set both properties in your .plist file.Then you will be good to go.

1.View controller-based status bar appearance -No

2.Status bar is initially hidden-YES

Hope this will help!

Comment: For ios 7 ,it should work  :                                              float versionOS;
versionOS=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
  if(versionOS>=7.0)
   {
         [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES
   }                                                                    Add this code into application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance
```

to NO
In your Info.plist file?

Comment: NO, I don't know how to do that. Can you please tell me how?

Though I HAVE tried to set it in the Attributes inspector for each of the View Controllers.

Comment: In the same way you added the key **Status bar is initially hidden**: Go to your target and then on the **Info** tab, inside **Custom iOS Target properties** add a new row and start typing the key I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work.

Both with and without the '[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];' line.

Comment: I've just created a test project that implements both **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];** in *application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* and *View controller-based status bar appearance* set to NO in the .plist and it works. I've zipped it, you can download it from here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61562421/StatusBarTest.zip

Answer (score 0):

In your **info.plist file**, there's a setting called **"Status bar is initially hidden."** Set that to "YES," and you won't have it at startup. Then you don't need to do anything in your code, the bar will show up when your app is launched.

Comment: You mean the bar will be hidden or it "will show up when (the) app is launched"?